# Processing multiple files concurrently in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, multicore

I am working on a VC6 project to be run on multicore processor PC. We require to process a large number of files. I am going to use multiple threads to process them. i need experts' advice to go ahead. This to my knowledge is case of data parallelism. The plot is like this.

Description of files :=

File structure is exactly the same but their names are arbitrary.

Size of around 100 kb each.

File number anything from few hundreds to few thousands.

Each file to be processed exactly the same way.

For each file,

I will read from HDD -> process -> Write to HDD

Saving may be in the same file or may be different folder with the same name ( Currently not decided so ignore )

I am thinking to use multiple threads to process the  files. So one file will be processed per core. (I know  file processing,thread creation, getting the number of cores)

DOUBT 1.

Now given say 1500 files and 2/4/8 cores how  should i divide  the files (appox.) equally among multiple threads, so that each file gets processed exactly once.

DOUBT 2. 
I have only one HDD so for I/O how many threads to create.

```
One thread for doing both Input and output 
OR 
Two threads, One for reading and one for writing.
```

Thank you in advance 
kanade

Comment: You can also consider [overlapped asynchronous operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#synchronization_and_file_position) to save yourself the hassle of threading.

Comment: With only one HDD, unless processing a file's contents takes a considerable amount of time, disk IO is going to be your bottleneck, and using multiple threads will not improve the overall runtime of your application.

Answer (score 4):

Unless the data processing is very slow, the limiting factor here will be disk access, so assuming all files are on the same physical disk and you're not using SSDs, I wonder if multitasking will help at all.

Besides, if you try to process multiple files in parallel, you will generate a lot of random disk accesses, which will most likely be much slower than accessing the files sequentially.
Trying to read and write in parallel will likely cause the same problem on a hard disk. Your HD's heads will go back and forth between the currently read and written files like crazy, dramatically reducing effective disk bandwidth.

My advice would be to have one thread per physical disk, doing first all the read and then all the writes. You can still have worker threads to process data in memory though.

Answer (score 0):

As other people have already said the bottleneck is likely to be the I/O throughput of your HDD.

**OSes Do a Lot Of Stuff Behind the Scenes**

Modern operating systems provide a lot of help in optimising the use of a HDD, and the HDD helps too. The OS (both Windows and Linux) will do a lot of caching of reads and writes, and it will speculatively read ahead. The HDD will likely support native command queuing, which will go a long way to re-ordering disk operations so as to avoid head thrashing. It will also have its own cache, several megabytes at least.

So you have to try quite hard to have a situation where your code is doing things that the OS and HDD haven't already guessed or delayed by caching, etc.

**Outwitting the OS**

One way to defeat that is to read randomly all over the file system, either within a single file or across multiple files. You're doing the latter.

The OS cannot guess what file you're going to open next. Once open it will guess that you're going to read a file sequentially and read ahead, and it will cache your file writes in RAM. But the initial open and read of the next file in your list will be delayed whilst the mechanism in your HDD slowly lumbers across the surface of the drive seeking the right track.

**Helping the OS to Help You**

Kichik suggested it is worth using overlapping IO to give the OS a hint as to what you want to read next. However that won't forewarn the OS about the next file.

What you might like to try is to open two files at once. The first is a file you're going to process, the second will be the next one that you will process. When you finish processing file 1 you close it, open file 3 and start processing file 2. You finish 2, close it, open file 4.

The idea is that by opening the next file early you are giving the OS a very big hint as to what you will be reading next, and it will likely read the first part of the file anyway on opening. My guess is that this initial sniff of the file will be done by the OS as and when it can be fitted in with whatever else is going on at the time. By the time you actually get around to reading that data from the file it will already have been cached.

If my guess is wrong then you can still open the files early and, as kichik said, use async I/O to tell the OS to read the first data whilst you're still busily processing the previous file. Doing an asynchronous open of the next file while processing the current file would be even better.